# How to pair via bluetooth on android automatically?

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth

I hope I could pair and connect with a known bluetooth device automatically.
My phone acts as the master part, while the device acts as the slave part.

I already know the slave device's Mac address and pin code.

How can I connect with the device with already-known MAC address and the pin code programmatically? which means there is no pairing UI.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a really useful [framework topic](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html) on the developer.android.com site.

One thing that isn't totally clear from that topic is that the device will automatically poll the user for the PIN.

Read the topic and try a few things. It's fairly straightforward.

Comment: Can I put the pin code in my code, so I can skip the paring UI?

Comment: thanks a lot. I only see bluetoothSocket.connect(), it seems there is no way to specify the pin code there.